# Client Object Model Question

Tags: client-object-model, api

I am working on a SharePoint site, and I want to parse the owner of the site from the API. I am currently using the following code:

```
var credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);
cc.Credentials = credentials; //cc is client context
Site web = cc.Site;
cc.Load(web);
cc.ExecuteQuery();
Console.WriteLine(web.Url);
```

I am occasionally getting a 503 Error when the execute query runs. Then I try to call the owner and that error persists. Do you know what causes the error and how I can get the owner of a sharepoint site through the api , either XML or Client object model?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the following example to the CSOM

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter Username: ");
        string username = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Enter Password: ");
        SecureString password = GetConsoleSecurePassword();
        string url = "site url";

        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(url);
        clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, password);

        Site site = clientContext.Site;     
        clientContext.Load(site);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

        Console.Write(site.Url);

        Console.Read();
    }

    private static SecureString GetConsoleSecurePassword()
    {
        SecureString pwd = new SecureString();
        while (true)
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo i = Console.ReadKey(true);
            if (i.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if (i.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
            {
                pwd.RemoveAt(pwd.Length - 1);
                Console.Write("\b \b");
            }
            else
            {
                pwd.AppendChar(i.KeyChar);
                Console.Write("*");
            }
        }
        return pwd;
    }
}
```